# Magento 2: how to get select "Sort by" value on category pages

Tags: magento2, category-products

How get values of choosen "Sort by" options.
[image]

Comment: What kind of values?

Comment: For example, i need get "Product Name" string, its value of SortBy dropdown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get current sort order using method `getOrder()` from class `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\ProductList\Toolbar`

Usage example:

```
class YourClassName
{
    protected $productListToolbar;

    // inject the Toolbar model here
    public function __construct(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $productListToolbar)
    {
        $this->productListToolbar = $productListToolbar;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        // use the injected Toolbar model here
        // to get current sort by
        $productOrder = $this->productListToolbar->getOrder();
        // to get current sort direction
        $productOrderDirection = $this->productListToolbar->getDirection();
    }
}
```

Other available methods are: `getMode()`, `getLimit()`, `getCurrentPage()`.

Comment: Thank you, its work fine.

Comment: so how can i get value Sort By "Relevance" in search product by tag page?